# How to pass a param to re.compile() string in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm learning beautifulsoup, and i'd like to use the regular expression to filter string.

For example, the html tag is:

```
<div>apple<\div>
<div>android<\div>
<div>windows<\div>
```

This code will be work:

```
re_words = re.compile(u".*(apple|android).*")

for content in body.findAll("div"):
    if re_words.match(content.text):
        print content.text
```

But i'd like to dynamically add keywords in regular expression, so i try to write this code:

```
word0 = "apple"
word1 = "android"

regular = "u""\".*("

regular += word0
regular += "|"
regular += word1

regular +=").*\""

re_words = re.compile(regular)

for content in body.findAll("div"):
    if re_words.match(content.text):
        print content.text
```

i failed to create a legal re.compile() this time. So someone would help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can pass the [compiled regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to the `text` argument of the `find_all()` call. To dynamically create regular expression I would put a placeholder into the parenthesis and join the keywords with `|`:

```
keywords = ["apple", "android"]
pattern = r"(%s)" % "|".join(keywords)
for content in body.find_all("div", text=re.compile(pattern)):
    print(content.text)
```

Alternatively, you can pass a [callable](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) as a `text` argument value:

```
keywords = ["apple", "android"]
for content in body.find_all("div", 
                             text=lambda text: any(keyword in text 
                                                   for keyword in keywords)):
    print(content.text)
```

---

Also note that, if you need to have an exact text match, you would not need regular expressions:

```
keywords = ["apple", "android"]
for content in body.find_all("div", text=keywords):
    print(content.text)
```

Comment: @pinchwang great, you can pass the flags to the compile call.

Comment: i need fuzzy matching, and unicode mode in the regular expression, so how to add the symbol ".*" and "u" ?   The regular expression need to be like re.compile(u".*(\u8d62|\u8f93).*")